# How to make sequently requests in RxJava2 as I stuck when having Flowable Data?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I’m adding item to server and if it successful the  message I receive is empty and if it successful  I need to make another request.
I think the map part isn't the right choice and I stuck when I want to set the list of data to adapter as I receive Flowable data while need simple data.

```
@POST("data”) Single<Response<Void>> addData(@Body Info body);

@GET("otherData”) Flowable<List<OtherData>> items();
```

`repository.addData(body)
    .map(new Function<Response<Void>, Flowable<List<OtherData>>>() {
     @Override
    public Flowable<List<OtherData>> apply(@NonNull Response<Void> voidResponse) throws Exception {
    return repository.items();} }).
.subscribe(items -> { //set to adapter I need not Flowable, need simple list              });`

Comment: Did you try .flatMap instead of .map?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I would like to know how it works? I want to understand the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look to official reactive documentation. You must be able to feel the differences between [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) and [flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html).

Comment: I don't understand why it make difference as it's only one item emitted how could it effect?

Comment: Well, its not easy to understand, but map transform one event to another, flatmap one, zero or more event.

Comment: The idea I understand but I don't understand in my sample, as only I have one event